# U-Boot RAM Test

Tags: linux, kernel, u-boot

I have an iMX6UL board,
i am doing U-Boot Ram Test RAM address range start from 0x80000000 to 0x90000000.
i need to find out the safe address range to perform U-boot- RAM test,
because some portion of Ram is containig U-Boot.
if i will perform RAM test for complete RAM then there are chances of RAM crash
to avoid this i need address range to for which i can perform test.

Thank you :)

Comment: See if you can build an instance of U-Boot that doesn't run in ram (e.g. runs directly from flash and uses cache as ram for stack etc) - then you don't need to avoid any part of ram in the test.